# ExtJS 3.4 : set combo store from ajax response

Tags: ajax, extjs, combobox

I have an ExrJs combo.

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        //store : myStore,
        //displayField : 'code',
        //valueField : 'code',
        fieldLabel : 'Tour Code',
        id : 'idTourCode',
        //allowBlank : false,
        typeAhead : true,
        forceSelection : true,
        mode : 'local',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        selectOnFocus : true,
        editable : false,
        hidden : false,
        disabled : true,
        minChars : 1,
        hideLabel : true,
        style : 'marginleft:10px',
        width : 361,
        emptyText : 'Tour Code'
        //flex : 1
    });
```

And I send an Ajax request and retrieve data from postgresql database and tried to set this response as the store of the combo as following.

```
var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                            console.log(jsonData);
                            if (jsonData.tourRef.length > 0) {
                                Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').bindStore(jsonData.tourRef);
                                Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').setRawValue(jsonData.tourRef.code);
                                Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').setHiddenValue(jsonData.tourRef.code);
                            }
```

My response is like this.

```
{'tourRef':[{ 'code' : '16/01/2014 17:31:03-ROUTE 5(COLOMBO 08,10)' } , { 'code' : '21/01/2014 10:27:54-ROUTE 5(COLOMBO 08,10)' }  ]}
```

Now the combo has two empty lines and firebug console says **Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').setHiddenValue(jsonData.tourRef.code);**

I am using ExtJs 3.4

What's wrong with my codes and how can I fix it.

Kind regards

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                          method: 'GET',
                          loadMask: true,
                          scope: this,
                          url: "http://" + host + "/" + projectName + "/"
                                + "TourReference",
                          success: function (response, request) {
                            Ext.MessageBox.alert('success', response.responseText);
                            var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                            console.log(jsonData);
                            if (jsonData.tourRef.length > 0) {
                                Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').bindStore(jsonData.tourRef);
                                Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').setRawValue(jsonData.tourRef.code);
                                Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').setHiddenValue(jsonData.tourRef.code);
                            }
                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                  title: 'Success',
                                  msg: 'success',
                                  buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                  icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
                            });

                          },
                          failure: function (response, request) {
                            Ext.MessageBox.alert('failure', response.responseText);
                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                  title: 'Error',
                                  msg: 'error',
                                  buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                  icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
                            });
                          },
                          params : {
                            dateFrom : Ext.getCmp('fromDateCombo').getValue(),
                            dateTo : Ext.getCmp('toDateCombo').getValue(),

                          }
                     });
```

Comment: Your combo hasn't store. That is a problem. You shouldn't use ajax request to fill combo list, you should store!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should solve your problem. Sorry for my poor english in comments.

```
var host = '127.0.0.1',
    projectName = 'superTours';

new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead : true,
    id: 'idTourCode', // this is VERY VERY bad. Try to don't use 'id' anywhere
    forceSelection : true,
    mode : 'local',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    editable : false,
    mode : 'local',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    disabled : true,
    hideLabel : true,
    style : 'marginleft: 10px;',
    width : 361,
    emptyText : 'Select a Tour Code',
    /* very important params below */
    valueField: 'code',
    displayField: 'code',
    store: {
        xtype: 'jsonstore',
        autoLoad: false, // I set this parameter to false to prevent automatical load data to store after combo render
        url: 'http://' + host + '/' + projectName + '/' + 'TourReference',
        root: 'tourRef',
        fields: [ 'code' ],
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records, options) {
                console.log('Combo store: data loaded');
            },
            loadexception: function() {
                // error while loading data
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As I can see, your combo must be disabled. With store parameter 'autoLoad: false' it will not be loaded until you want to.

If you want to send date period to script, you should remove 'change' and 'select' listeners from datefields and add 'Show' button. This button will send datefield params to server. Add this code to button's handler:

```
handler:function(Btn) {
    var datefrom = Ext.getCmp('fromDateCombo').getValue(),
        dateto = Ext.getCmp('toDateCombo').getValue();
    Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').enable();
    Ext.getCmp('idTourCode').getStore().reload({
        params: {
            dateFrom: datefrom,
            dateTo: dateto
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is this store ajax request should send when user select a date in a data field

Comment: How should I apply this into listener of the date field ?

Comment: Yes. Use my code for combo and load data to store when you want. Dont forget to set combo enabled. If you use 'datefield', you can add this store load code to 'select' and  'change' listeners.

Comment: it doesn't take dateFrom and dateTo values

Comment: baseParams or params ?

Comment: I use param then it takes null value

Comment: [Object { api={...}, url="http://192.168.1.184:8080/Ornox/TourReference", events={...}, more...}, Object { request={...}, reader={...}, scope={...}, more...}, Object { tId=22, status=200, statusText="OK", more...},
SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
 

return json ? eval("(" + json + ")") : "";

Comment: Try to put json result into rounded brackets. Like ({ tourRef : [...]})

Comment: I edit my code in post above and comment how to use store load in your case.

Comment: Button for datefield?

Comment: Ext.getCmp(...).getStore(...).setBaseParam(...) is undefined

Comment: If you have two date fields where you can set dateFrom and dateTo, just add a simple button near this fields. This will allow load data by user's click.
Also you can set store load action to 'change' and 'select' events in dateTo field. Do not forget to check date fields values to prevent errors on server (it shouldn't be empty). Once again I am sorry for my english!

Comment: And I added load action to select event

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45701/discussion-between-andrew-koshkin-and-ann18)